# WSO2 EMM SSO folders

Tags: wso2

I am trying to understand how SSO works in WSO2 EMM. I am looking through the directory structure of the source code and found that there are 2 different SSO folders. What are the purposes of each of these 2 folders?

(1) [WSO2EMM HOME]/modules/sso

(2) [WSO2EMM HOME]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/sso

In (1) I can see the functions to handle SAML requests/response but isn't this handled by the individual jaggeryapps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to handle the SAML request then you can use  [WSO2EMM HOME]/modules/sso.
other folder is used to Login function.